# Convert dwg file to pdf

Tags: pdf, autocad

I'm quite new to AutoCAD and has been asked to write a C# utility that can convert a .dwg file to pdf. I've been googling around and haven't figured out any way yet. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are automating AutoCAD then just simply send a command to plot the appropriate layout using the `DWG to PDF.pc3` printer. You're looking for `SendStringToExecute()` or `SendCommand()` if you are using COM.

C# is overkill for this, even if you are batch-plotting thee are commands built into AutoCAD for this. See the AutoCAD `Publish` command.

Edit in response to comment below. 
You should look at https://developer.autodesk.com/api/autocadio/ - it's AutoCAD as a web service.

Comment: The full requirements is when I upload a DWG file to an ASP.NET MVC site, that file is automatically converted to PDF and store on site. So I think  you guide won't work in this case

Comment: indeed to convert from .DWG to .PDF you'll need AutoCAD (or an equivalent library). The AutoCAD I/O option should work and it's transparent to the user, look at the default dwgtopdf task.

Comment: Yes I just checked the Autocad I/O and gave iit a try. It worked. However just want to ask if there's any other solution, just in case the server is not allowed to access outside services

Comment: Yeah but you're not going to like it - install RealDwg on your server. Got a spare US$5k? See http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=770257 and when it comes to building the installer you may briefly consider suicide - it is not a fun process.