# Batch plotting dwg & dxf files to pdf in AutoCAD

Tags: pdf, autocad, dxf, dwg

I have a problem with making the batch plotting files in the autoCAD.

The similar query is here, but it solves an issue within 1 file only.

[Convert dwg file to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536367/convert-dwg-file-to-pdf/37536759#37536759)

In turn, the main tutorial doesn't explain it enough.

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-publish-multiple-drawings-into-PDF-in-AutoCAD.html

I have the problem with creating the batch list itself.

My problem looks like this.

I have got a command "Layout not initialized", as per below:

[image]

As a result I have got nothing.

Is anyone able to help?

Comment: I think you are supposed to have already setup your paper space layout and configured its printing properties. Then you can use batch plotting. It sound slike you only have your drawing in modelspace and have no layout defined (which is used to print to PDF).

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me how to do that? Thank you in advance

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the Autocad knowledge base. You are bound to find lots of advice on paper space layouts and batch plotting. For example: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-60D46D10-2934-44D4-8B4A-D969E284140C-htm.html

Comment: Another: https://tutorial45.com/autocad-batch-plot/

Comment: Another: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-9A301B51-BFFF-4BC9-983C-938D6B5DAB2F-htm.html

Comment: Google is your friend!

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is running the command PAGESETUP and setting the page layout for each document, as follows:
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/layout-not-initialized-when-publish.html

[image]